# Android button loses text alignment after setText

Tags: android, text, button, alignment

I'm using xml to draw a spinning progress indicator along with some text. In the bottom of the screen I have a TableLayout with two buttons, which are centered in the page with each text also centered.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progresscontainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_bar" 
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/progress_text" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="First text" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="3dip"
    android:background="@color/buttonbar"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1">

    <TableRow>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

In the code I have a runnable that after a couple of seconds changes the text on the progress_text TextView.

```
private Runnable mTimeTask = new Runnable() {

   public void run() {
       TextView progressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progress_text);
       progressText.setText("Second text");
   }

};
```

The problem is that after this setText(), once I focus on one of the buttons, the text loses it's centered alignment and goes all the way to the left. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had this problem but the button's text was becoming bottom aligned. I have posted a new Q&A here along with my solution, which involved hiding and showing the button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514288/buttons-text-gets-wrong-alignment-after-a-settext-call-on-a-textview

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem too. It seems that `setText()` changes the gravity settings, so I had to reapply them using:

```
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to reset it's **padding** to:

```
button.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

With value:

```
button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Good answer.  If the button has built-in padding, then gravity won't necessarily put the text right where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here worked for me so I tried to find my own way to fix it and was messing with a TextView that has the same alignment problem but when I added the line `android:maxLines="1"` it suddenly worked so I tried it on the button and it worked.

Just add the `android:maxLines="1"` to the definition of your button and the text alignment should stay after setting a new text.

Comment: Plus one. This worked also with an ExtendedFloatingActionButton runtime in a fragment through `((activity_main) requireActivity()).my_efab.setMaxLines(1);`