# Button's text gets wrong alignment after a setText() call on a TextView

Tags: android

In my case I have an `activity` with a `TableLayout` which contains a few views such as a `Button` with id 'Number1' and a `TextView` with id 'password'.

When I hit the button, its event handler gets called and one of the things it does is set the password `TextView` text. After this, the button's text becomes misaligned - instead of the original center alignment, the text inside the button becomes aligned at the bottom.

I am using Android Studio 1.1 Beta 4 and the project has compileSdkVersion set to 21, minSdkVersion set to 19 and targetSdkVersion set to 21.

Below I have provided snippets of the relevant code.

Event handler snippet ...

```
public void buttonNumberClick(View view) {

    TextView passwordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);

    Button sourceButton = (Button)view;

    String sourceText = sourceButton.getText().toString();
    String text = passwordText.getText().toString();
    if (text.length() < 4) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(sourceText);
        String newText = text + Integer.toString(number);

        // After this below line, the button text of the clicked button (Number1) becomes bottom aligned.
        passwordText.setText(newText);

    }
}
```

Layout snippet ...

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:minHeight="130dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/enterPinTextView"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:text="Enter PIN"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressRing"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="5.0"
                    android:id="@+id/progressRingText"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonTest"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:onClick="buttonTestClick" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Number1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:onClick="buttonNumberClick" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: A downvote with no comment. Thanks for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the few similar occurrences on Stack Overflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195426/android-button-loses-text-alignment-after-settext), I tried a few different things including programmatically setting the text of the Button and also setting its gravity and padding again. None of this worked.

I arrived at this solution by trial and error - Hide and then show the button before and after the offending call to setText. Also, note that you have to set visibility to GONE rather than INVISIBLE. This is possibly forcing the layout engine to create the button again, with the correct alignment.

New event handler shown below.

```
public void buttonNumberClick(View view) {

    TextView passwordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);

    Button sourceButton = (Button)view;

    String sourceText = sourceButton.getText().toString();
    String text = passwordText.getText().toString();
    if (text.length() < 4) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(sourceText);
        String newText = text + Integer.toString(number);

        // Fix the issue of the button text being mis-aligned after the below call to setText.
        sourceButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        passwordText.setText(newText);

        // Fix the issue of the button text being mis-aligned after the above call to setText.
        sourceButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```